# Laravel 5.5 Paginate the Query - Eager Loading

Tags: laravel, pagination, loading, eager

I have a problem and can't figure out how to solve it. I've searched online but still couldn't get a firm answer. What I'm trying to do is to paginate Inquiries table - or the query below. Everything seems to work (at least I'm getting 20 inquiries per page, however I can't figure out how to display the links()?

I'm saving Inquiries in the $thecusts collection and passing it to the view. 
Tables and relations : Employees - Dealers (manytomany)
Dealers-customers(1 to many)
Customers-inquiries (1 to many).

So I need to paginate x Inquiries for the employee that has many dealers.

Anyone can help ?

```
$justch = $me->employeehasdealers()->get(['dealers.dealer_id','dealer','abbreviation']); //list of dealers assigned to auth employee
$justch2=$justch->load(['DealerHasInquiries'=>function($query){
    $query->with('inquiriescomments:comments_inquiries_id,inquiry_id,employee_id,comments','inquiryspdl','inquiriescustomers:customer_id,customer')->paginate(20);
}]);


$thecusts = new Collection();
foreach ($justch2 as $just) {
    $thecusts = $thecusts->merge($just->DealerHasInquiries);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you go the other way, e.g., get inquiries corresponding to those dealers and paginate those.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry I'm still learning laravel and this question might be stupid but how do I paginate inquries for dealers since between Dealers table and Inquiries table I got customers table? I can get the customers first, but this way the duration is twice bigger

Comment: Well it might look something like `Inquiry::whereHas("dealer", function ($q) use ($me) { $q->whereHas("employee", function ($q) use ($me) { $q->id = $me->id; }); })->paginate(20);` or you can check `https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through` to be able to get them directly from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're not passing back the `paginator` instance. You can manually create one in your controller based on `$thecusts`:

```
$perPage=20;
return view('my-view', ['paginator' => new Paginator($thecusts->toArray(), $perPage)]);
```

Then you can call the links method on the `paginator` instance in your view:

```
{{ $paginator->links() }}
```

**Edit**

You may be able to simply all this though in a single query like:

```
$thecusts = $me->employeehasdealers()->with(['DealerHasInquiries'=>function($query){
    $query->with('inquiriescomments:comments_inquiries_id,inquiry_id,employee_id,comments','inquiryspdl','inquiriescustomers:customer_id,customer');
}])->paginate(20);

return view('my-view, compact('thecusts'));
```

Comment: Yes, this was my initial query, however I changed it so I could solve the issue with pagination. Now you gave me the true answer, I had to pass the paginator instance and I appreciate it a lot! Thank you !!!

Comment: Right on, glad it worked for you. Go ahead and click that check mark next to the answer too ;)

Answer (score 0):

> however I can't figure out how to display the links()?

You can do this in your blade:

```
{{ $justch2->links() }}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't work: Method links does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer has been posted by [btl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320487/btl) - (Much appreciate it!)

Here is my code with some additions:

Controller:

```
$perpage=19;     
 $justch = $me->employeehasdealers()->with(['DealerHasInquiries'=>function($query) use ($perpage){
            $query->with('inquiriescomments:comments_inquiries_id,inquiry_id,employee_id,comments','inquiryspdl','inquiriescustomers:customer_id,customer')->simplePaginate($perpage);
        }])->get(['dealers.dealer_id','dealer','abbreviation']);
     foreach ($justch as $just) {
                $thecusts = $thecusts->merge($just->DealerHasInquiries);
                           }

     $paginator = new Paginator($thecusts->toArray(),$perpage, Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(),['path'=>Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]);
    $inquiries = $thecusts;

    return view('/inquiries', ['paginator'=>$paginator,'inquiries' => $inquiries]);
```

Blade: `{{$paginator->links()}}`